# Add real-time marker with watchPosition() in Ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3

I'm struggling with adding marker into my google-map with real-time location data from `watchPosition()` method. When I use `getCurrentPosition()` method everything works just fine. But with this method, I can't solve this. So, in general, I want to create marker with real-time position of the user and change the position of that marker in the map based on how user is moving or not.
Thanks for your replies!

Here is my code:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public location: Geolocation) {}

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.location.getCurrentPosition().then(
      position => {
        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude,
          position.coords.longitude
        );

        let mapOptions = {
          center: latLng,
          zoom: 15
        };

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(
          this.mapElement.nativeElement,
          mapOptions
        );
        this.getPosition();
        console.log(this.map);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

  getPosition() {
    this.location.watchPosition().subscribe(
      (pos: Geoposition) => {
        this.currentPos = pos;
        console.log(pos);
        this.addMainMarker(pos);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

  addMainMarker(markerPos) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      position: markerPos
    });
  }
}
```